# Change Bootstrap-Table Icon

Tags: bootstrap-table

As a start, I would like to change one of the FontAwesome icon on the button in the Bootstrap-Table. For example, I would like to change the columns toggle icon as shown below

[image]

I have read the documentation on Bootstrap-Table icons through this link: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#icons . However, it seems that I cannot just replace the value on one of the icon properties with the one I want. I tried to create my own custom CSS to manipulate the button's icon to change but to no avail. I have also read other StackOverflow posts regarding this matter, but I cannot follow or understand their solutions. It would be helpful if anyone can provide me a step by step on how to change the FontAwesome icons on one of the buttons in the Bootstrap-Table table. Thanks!

I tried to change the column toggle icon by replacing its value in the `table-options.md` file that has the following code.

### icons

- **Attribute:** `data-icons`
- **Type:** `Object`
- **Detail:**

  Defines icons used in the toolbar, pagination, and details view.
- **Default:**

  {% highlight html %}
  {
  paginationSwitchDown: 'fa-caret-square-down',
  paginationSwitchUp: 'fa-caret-square-up',
  refresh: 'fa-sync',
  toggleOff: 'fa-toggle-off',
  toggleOn: 'fa-toggle-on',
  columns: 'fa-th-list', <------------ Tried to replace this value with 'fa-solid fa-table-columns', for example
  fullscreen: 'fa-arrows-alt',
  detailOpen: 'fa-plus',
  detailClose: 'fa-minus'
  }
  {% endhighlight %}
- **Example:** [Table Icons](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/table-icons.html)

Unfortunately, nothing changed to the icon.

Comment: A file with the suffix `.md` means this is a file written in markdown. This is _documentation_ for the framework, not actual code.

Comment: My mistake, I searched for 'data-icons' keyword through the Bootstrap-Table folder to which I found this .md file. I'll leave it be then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of using another icon set in the Bootstrap Table docs. [This example uses ionicons.](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#options/icons-prefix.html)

Also, I think the docs are outdated in terms of using FontAwesome. I believe it actually uses [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) by default.

Comment: Ah thank you! I must have missed that statement in the introduction section of the documentation since I directly jumped into the API section of Table Options.